# media:thumbnail w/ BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, rss, beautifulsoup

What is the correct way to parse the `url` attribute of `media:thumbnail` tags using BeautifulSoup? I have tried the following:

```
doc = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss'), 'xml')
items = doc.findAll('item')
for item in items:
    title = item.title.text
    link = item.link.text
    image = item.find('media:thumbnail')[0]['url']
```

However, I get the `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't include the namespace prefix:

```
>>> doc.find('thumbnail')
<media:thumbnail height="51" url="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/150116173806-amateur-video-amedy-coulibaly-top-tease.jpg" width="90"/>
```

The `element.find()` method returns **one** element, so there is no need for subscription here; you can access the `url` attribute on the element directly:

```
>>> doc.find('thumbnail')['url']
u'http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/150116173806-amateur-video-amedy-coulibaly-top-tease.jpg'
```

There currently isn't any support for searching by a specific namespace; the namespace *URL* is stored (in the `.namespace` attribute) but not used by `.find()` or `.find_all()`.